# .LAZ file will not align with open street map in QGIS 3.28.7

Tags: qgis, coordinate-transformation, cartesian-coordinates

I downloaded a point cloud file of a region in the UK as a .LAZ from the Defra Survey Data download site and have converted it to an OSGB36 EPSG 4277 CRS.  I wanted to underlaylay an OSM of the same area, so imported an OSM layer and also set it the same CRS.  The Project CRS is also set to the same. I was expecting the two layers to overlap, however they are very far off.  I wondered what I was not doing correctly and what else I should do to get these two layers to align?
Thank you.